# Refresh a webpage automatically from within a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a loop that runs through a variety of websites and I'd like to put some kind of a postback in the loop so that each time through a textbox would refresh with the url that is currently being considered.  I don't know AJAX yet so I'd like to redo the webpage.  I am currently using a session variable to hold data for display between page loads.
     I have tried

1) Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

2) Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");

3) Page_Load(sender, e);

4) this.RaisePostBackEvent(URLTextBox.Text);

but they don't work, possibly because I am not implementing them properly.  I'd like to watch the current situation as it is updated within the loop.  Any ideas?
     Thanks,
            bsperlin

Comment: What kind of "loop" are you talking about?  Some kind of javascript loop?  Can we see some code?

Comment: Can you detail out how you have implemented a loop and where the textbox is?

Comment: It appears you are crawling websites and you would like to see the url of the page being crawled ?

Comment: I'm using C# and there is a loop in a function called by a button push.  The loop is a "for" loop walking through an arraylist of pairs.  Future URLs are scraped off of the source of each web page and are saved for later use.  I would like to know which URL is being downloaded and scraped each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but is not a recommended approach

Put your text box inside an `updatepanel` linked with a `timer control` and bind `text box` to a class variable, which is updated every time a new url is considered. You can update textbox in `Timer_Tick` event .

```
Timer_Tick
{ 
  UrlTextBox.Text = urlconsidered; 
}
```

have a look at this tutorial

- [**Introduction to the UpdatePanel
  Control**](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdatePanel.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't looking for something that would be dependent on a certain time interval, but rather every time through the loop, when a new URL was being considered, the update to the page/textbox would occur.  Is that possible?